# Redux(toolkit) keep old data

Tags: asynchronous, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, react-typescript

I use redux-toolkit in a react-typescript app and I have a common slice that shares data among different components. For avoiding the leak of the data, I added

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        dispatch(resetCollectionData());
    };
}, []);
```

The issue is the dispatch is asynchronous so when the new route gets loaded(navigate to new route), I still have the old data for a fraction of time. This makes the new route break. Is it a way to guarantee that `resetCollectionData()` does its job before leaving the page? Otherwise, I need to create a couple of highly similar slices or add unnecessary check/verify logic

Does dispatch have a flag that shows an action still is ongoing? similar to isSuccess or isFetching in RTK Query?

Comment: Why not dispatch the action before navigating? If it's an async thunk, then it's a promise and you can wait the accomplish of it.

Comment: Do you mean to add the dispatch(resetCollectionData()); to the react-router NavLink?

Comment: @LinDu Adding the onClick listener to the router NavLink and dispatching the action there worked for me as it gets executed before the component cleanup and guarantees to reset the stale data.

Answer (score 0):

Lets add additional state on slice

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const commonSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'common',
  initialState: {
    // other state properties
    resetting: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    resetCollectionData: (state) => {
      // reset data logic
    },
    resetCollectionDataStart: (state) => {
      state.resetting = true;
    },
    resetCollectionDataComplete: (state) => {
      state.resetting = false;
    },
  },
});

export const {
  resetCollectionData,
  resetCollectionDataStart,
  resetCollectionDataComplete,
} = commonSlice.actions;

export default commonSlice.reducer;
```

Then use it as following

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const resetting = useSelector((state) => state.common.resetting);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(resetCollectionDataStart());
    dispatch(resetCollectionData());
    dispatch(resetCollectionDataComplete());

    return () => {
      dispatch(resetCollectionData());
    };
  }, [dispatch]);

  if (resetting) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  // Render your component

  return <div>Component Content</div>;
};
```

Comment: This is not working as all dispatch will be triggered after mounting. There are some extra actions like a SnackBar inside a useeffect are involved and that triggers when stale data comes to the component on getting mounted